# Data structure for walking around in a simple maze with three types of walls

Tags: data-structures, maze

Actually my real problem has not much to do with mazes, but it can be nicely described as such:

Imagine standing in a maze whose walls are aligned along a cartesian grid. The walls are not visible and there are three types of them:

1. (N) no wall, you can pass through.
2. (S) solid wall, you are blocked when you run against it.
3. (F) fatal wall, you die when you run against it.

Every move is from one cell to a neighboring cell and I want to determine what happens on every move.

Simple solution: I use coordinates for my grid like this:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 +---+---+---+
2 |   |   |   |
3 +---+---+---+
```

I only save the solid and fatal walls, and not the corners. Together with the type of wall this makes triples:

```
(1,2,S), (1,4,S), (1,6,F), (2,1,S) ...
```

On every move I calculate the position of the wall and look it up in my triples. (2,2) to (2,4) -> is there a wall on position (2,3)?

So the question now is what kind of data structures would be suitable to improve this? Firstly only half of my coordinates can be walls so one could reduce here. But space is probably a minor concern. More important is the time complexity to extract information: how can I easily look up the type of wall in this structure for a certain move without going through all triples like in the simple solution? To clarify: The next move will always start from the end of the previous move.

Additional information: in my real problem the maze is a maximum of 3x3 cells big, and it's just one room without any walls standing inside the room, only enclosing walls. I'm also interested in saving the maze in a readable way in JSON or XML format, but that is probably a different question as it might conflict with the aim of the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what would work for your maze would be some sort of bi-directional multi-linked list of your cells, essentially a graph of linked cells, which you can move all directions in. Each of your cells would have neighboring cells in four directions, which it has links to.

```
     UP              UP
LEFT    RIGHT<->LEFT     RIGHT
    DOWN            DOWN
```

Here, `RIGHT` and `LEFT` are the links to the neighboring cell, respectively to the position of the cell.
Now you can easily accomplish this by having a cell object point to another and at the same time give each cell four walls, which you can define as being however you want them to. This way allows you to add and remove cells from your maze as well as traverse the maze by using simple methods. How you define your cells, is obviously your own decision, but if you want to export them easily, you can give each of them coordinates. Essentially this is how I would build a class that does this for you:

```
Cell
    Cell left, right, up, down //links to neighbors (can also be pointers)
    Wall leftWall, rightWall, upWall, downWall //the walls of the cell
    Coordinate coordinate //if needed
```

methods to access cells would look like this:

```
//go left
if leftWall is passable
    go to left //e.g. return left cell
else if leftWall is deadly
    end //or so
else
    do stuff
```

If you want coordinates to export the cells easily, you can assign them upon creation, depending on where you add them, for example assume a cell is at (0,1) and you create a cell to the right using a method `addRight` you could set the coordinates of the new cell automatically to (0,2) since the cells are "aware" of their neighbors, due to them being linked.

Furthermore, traversing a linked list from the outside can be done easily, by having one object/reference, which is your current position and changing it to be the one you are moving to. For example:

```
Cell currentCell = some cell
currentCell = currentCell.goLeft //checks if there is a wall to the left
```

If there is no wall, 'currentCell' will now hold the reference to the cell of the left of your starting cell.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple representation is an NxM matrix (two-dimensional array) of bytes. Each wall is represented by two bits. Since each cell has four walls, you can store all four walls in just 8 bits.

Define your wall types as:

```
wallTypeNone = 0;
wallTypeSolid = 1;
wallTypeFatal = 2;
wallTypeInvalid = 3;  // should never see this
```

Now, map the left wall to the two low bits, top wall to bits 2 and 3, etc.

```
leftWallType = wallType & 0x03;
topWallType = (wallType >> 2) & 0x03;
rightWallType = (wallType >> 4) & 0x03;
bottomWallType = (wallType >> 6) & 0x03;
```

You can save about half the space, at the cost of a little code complexity by using an implicit left wall for the left column, and an implicit top wall for the top row. A cell then "owns" only two walls: the bottom and right. If you want the left wall for a cell, then you query the right wall of the adjacent cell. And if you want the top wall for a cell, you query the bottom wall of the cell above. That allows you to store each cell in just four bits. So your array is size N/2 x M. It's slightly slower (on the order of nanoseconds) to query a left or top wall, because it takes a few more instructions. But you require fewer memory accesses to traverse the entire maze.